# Diagonalizing the sum of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, block-matrices

Consider the matrix
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
H_{1} & 0\\
0 & H_{2}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{cc}
R_{1} & R_{2}\\
R_{1} & R_{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are negative definite and symmetric matrices over the reals, and where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric matrices over the reals. Notice the block nature of $A$.

I would like to diagonalize $A$, that is finding an invertible matrix $M$ such that $M^{-1}KM$ is diagonal. I am hoping that there is a way to take advantage of $K$'s specific structure to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do any of these matrices commute ?

Comment: @Lelouch No... would that help?

Comment: First you have to specify (i) are the matrices over the reals, the complex numbers, the integers, an arbitrary field, a commutative ring with identity? (ii) what you mean by "diagonalizing a matrix $K$ . Do you seek an invertible matrix $M$ such that $M^{-1}KM$ is diagonal or such that $M^TKM$ is diagonal or such that $M$ is orthogonal and $M^TKM$ is diagonal or two invertible matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M_1KM_2$ is  diagonal with $d_i$ dividing $d_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: @P.Lawrence Apologies, I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: FYI unless $R_1=R_2$, the matrix $A$ will not be Hermitian and that's making it quite more complex (no pun intended).

Comment: Isn't this close to a rank-1 update?  Didn't you post a similar question recently?